# Asynchronous Laravel Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to run asynchronous Laravel jobs and work forever. As far as I understand, I need to setup Jobs and push them into separate queues.

I have set `.env` - `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` and run `php artisan queue:table` and `php artisan migrate` accordingly.

and I have run `php artisan make:job MyJob`

*(at this point queues table is empty though, but I don't know if I did something wrong)*

The point I mainly got confused is how is it going to start all the jobs and run them forever, or run the job initially?

As far as I understand, to trigger the job I need to call:

```
MyFirstJob::dispatch();
```

but where do I need to call it to work all the time and forever?

Comment: you can use a process monitoring tool for this like supervisor and monit, checkout this supervisor config given by LARAVEL documentation itself https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: You also have to understand how `Queues` work, a Queue is just a list of JOB, for those jobs to be `PROCESSED` you will need to have a `WORKER` to run a laravel worker simply run `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: But if I run `php artisan queue:work`, I won't be able to run any other commands in the linux where I run other commands right? I am so confused and I couldn't find any useful resources around. I'd be grateful if you can suggest any links or add an answer. I understand workers and jobs approach but I couldn't find how to execute it. Also, is 'database' queue bad for such task (or why would I use supervisor instead)? I am trying to run various http calls to get data from various apis

Comment: read my first comment :) That should solve your problem

Comment: @AlleoIndong I setup supervisor and it seems to work, however my problem is that my jobs table is empty. In earlier versions I could add `--queued` flag but I didn't understand how to achieve this on 5.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here from Laravel 6  and I got the same issue... table jobs always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put all jobs

```
$schedule->job(new Job1)->everyMinute(); 
$schedule->job(new Job2)->everyMinute(); 
$schedule->job(new Job3)->everyMinute();
```

under schedule() function in kernel.php and than scheduler will handle all the jobs.

Comment: Seriously? This is for cron (scheduled tasks), You only need to do this if you have a job that you want to run every single minute. To add a new job on the queue, you just have to `implement ShouldQueue` on an event, then dispatch that event whenever needed

Comment: $schedule->command('your-command')->everyMinute(); you can use run command every minute as well as you can set job which I mentioned above, then configuration made in your scheduler will check your kernel file for any job or event command is set to run any task or not and based on that it will set all those tasks in jobs table