# maxAttemptsExceededException : Laravel Jobs fails because of max attempts or timeout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have checked the questions asked before but did not find the solution I need. Here is the question list,
[Laravel & Laravel Forge returns “MaxAttemptsExceededException:” even when tries are set at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416437/laravel-laravel-forge-returns-maxattemptsexceededexception-even-when-tries), [Asynchronous Laravel Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007337/asynchronous-laravel-jobs), [Laravel job overwriting other jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663274/laravel-job-overwriting-other-jobs)

What I'm trying is to convert all the videos(Maybe in MBs or GBs) with the help of FFMPEG using the Laravel jobs on the button click event.

Without using the Job, the code is working properly.

Here is the code Sample of Controller,

```
public function uploadSelected(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $ids = explode(',', $input['ids']);
    $this->dispatch(new FTPConverting($ids, 0));
    return redirect()->to('videos/ftp-videos');
}
```

And in the job, the handle is like this

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach ($this->videos as $id) {
        if (file_exists(storage_path('app/public/temp_videos/' . $id))) {
            copy(storage_path('app/public/temp_videos/' . $id), storage_path('app/public/temp_videos/uploaded/' . $id));
            $video = TempVideo::create([
                        'original_name' => $id,
                        'disk' => 'public',
                        'video_path' => 'temp_videos/uploaded/' . $id
            ]);
            $this->video_without_watermark($video->video_path, $video->id, $video->disk);
            $this->streaming_without_watermark($video->video_path, $video->id, $video->disk);
            if ($video->upload_status == 'Converted') {
                unlink(storage_path('app/public/temp_videos/' . $id));
                unlink(storage_path('app/public/temp_videos/uploaded/' . $id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the functions, `video_without_watermark` and `streaming_without_watermark`, there is the logic to convert files with the help of FFMPEG.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or possible solution to this.

**Edit**
The log of the failed job table

> Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\FTPConverting has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in /var/www/html/screwbox/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:401

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes @KieronWiltshire just created failed_jobs table and the issue was resolved

Comment: if you want to start your queue job continuously do this cmd 
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 
or specify your --timeout= with seconds that you want